# How do i alter the quicklaunch navbars using the onet file?

Tags: navigation, quick-launch, onet

I have the following markup in my onet file.  All i want to do is show these 2 sections in the quick launch area and NOTHING else.  The code below adds these 2 sections but also adds extra sections e.g. Libraries, Recently Modified

I dont want to add css or javascript to hide unwanted navbars.

```
<NavBars>
<NavBar Name="a" Url="myurl1" ID="1008">
  <NavBarPage Name="b" Url="myurl2" />
  <NavBarPage Name="c" Url="myurl3" />
</NavBar>
<NavBar Name="d" Url="myurl4" ID="1009">
  <NavBarPage Name="e" Url="myurl5" />
</NavBar>
<NavBars>
```

How do i do this in the onet file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint automatically set those links in the quicklaunch. I suggest to create a feature with a receiver and add this feature to your ONET. Programmatically add those links to the quicklaunch.

Example:

```
SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode navNode = new SPNavigationNode("MyLink", "http://mylink.com",false);
nodes.AddAsFirst(navNode);
```

Btw. "Recently modified" is a section only available within Wiki page libraries. You can only hide this by hiding a placeholder in the masterpage or with some CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.s4-recentchanges
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```